# What is the name of variable ending in = {} () Swift?

Tags: swift

I have been digging through the Swift documentation trying to find the name of the Swift syntax below.

```
static let taskDateFormat: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    return formatter
}()
```

I do not know what to call this syntax.  I am confused by the = {} () component.  What is this called?

Comment: For further reading, this is commonly referred to as an immediately executed (or invoked) closure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's code that generates the default `DateFormatter` value for the `taskDateFormat` property.

As per the Swift manual (emphasis mine):

> https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html
>
> #### Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function
>
> If a stored property’s default value requires some customization or setup, you can use a closure or global function to provide a customized default value for that property. Whenever a new instance of the type that the property belongs to is initialized, the closure or function is called, and its return value is assigned as the property’s default value.
>
> **Note that the closure’s end curly brace is followed by an empty pair of parentheses**. This tells Swift to execute the closure immediately. If you omit these parentheses, you are trying to assign the closure itself to the property, and not the return value of the closure.

Basically the code pre-initializes the `taskDateFormat` property to a new `DateFormatter` object and sets the `dateStyle` property before the `taskDateFormat` property is set.

Comment: Excellent.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `= {}()` means a **block** (a.k.a **closure**) , it can return anything.

Since your variable is `DateFormatter` Type, it will expect a `DateFormatter` instance being returned from the block.

That Type on the variable is mandatory, you can have a hint on it if you remove the variable Type, you will get the error:
`Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate`